# Trying to send multiple SMS via twilio in Google Appscript but keep getting errors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, twilio-api

Trying to send multiple SMS via twilio in Google Appscript but keep getting errors

Tried this, but the steps are not so clear : https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/02/send-sms-from-a-google-spreadsheet.html

The author said to define "to" and "body" under Myfunction but the example doesn't show that.

Perhaps i understand it wrongly.

```
function sendSms(to, body) {

var ACCOUNT_SID = "#########################";
var ACCOUNT_TOKEN = "#########################";
var messages_url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + ACCOUNT_SID + "/Messages.json";

  var payload = {
    "To": "01#######",
    "Body" : "#### Test",
    "From" : "+1201########"
  };

  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    "payload" : payload
  };

  options.headers = { 
    "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(messages_url, options);
}

function sendAll() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 31) 
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    try {
      response_data = sendSms(row[29], row[30]);
      status = "Msg Sent";
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log(err);
      status = "Error";
    }
    sheet.getRange(startRow + Number(i), 31).setValue(status);
  }
}

function specialFunction() {
//var to = "";
//var body = "Tender"
//sendSms(to,body);
sendAll();
}
```

Error:

1. 30008 - Unknown error
2. The "Error" or "Msg_Sent" always exceeds my current number of rows(11 rows) but goes upto 18 rows where there isnt a corresponding data to sms.

Comment: Please include the code and the errors so someone might be able to solve the issue

Comment: @James Z, thanks. I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `payload` in `sendSms` you're overwriting `to`, you don't want to do this:

```
var payload = {
  "To": "+60168522468",
  "Body" : "RM0.00 Test",
  "From" : "+12014313278"
};
```

Replace `"To": "+60168522468",` with `"To": to,` otherwise the SMS is always send to the same recipient.

Also make sure that the rest of the rows are really empty as `getLastRow()` returns *the position of the last row that has content*, see the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()).

If possible try to share a sample of the spreadsheet so that we can investigate further.

Comment: Thank you @yvesonline